# Scrapy. The creation of complex structures in parsing result (dict in dict)

Tags: parsing, scrapy

I have the few Item's objects that describe the properties of the object

```html
import scrapy


class FullName(scrapy.Item):
    first = scrapy.Field()
    second = scrapy.Field()
    middle = scrapy.Field()

class Physical(scrapy.Item):
    growth = scrapy.Field()
    weight = scrapy.Field()
    hair = scrapy.Field()
```

And I have the Item, which belongs to the subject. As fields I want to insert the Item's properties of the object

```html
class Human(scrapy.Item):
    sex = scrapy.Field()
    age = scrapy.Field()
    physical = <...Physical Item>
    full_name = <...FullName Item>
```

so when you export data to a structure with the specified nesting

```
{
age: 23,
sex: male,
full_name: {first: test, second: test, middle: test}
physical: {growth: 90, height: 190, hair: blonde},
...
}
```

nesting can be to any depth.

cat i do it with Scrapy? What structure for spiders? in scrapy docs about [extending item](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/items.html#extending-items) и [loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/loaders.html), i can't find.

or I chose the wrong tool and I need to do manually?

---

UPD. About spiders.

What structure for spider? As you know, the field 'physical' we need to associate with spider PhysicalSpider, which pass current url. How do it? Fix me, please.

```
class PhysicalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "physical"

    def parse(self, response):
         item = PhysicalItem()
         item['weight'] = response.xpath('path').extract()
         yield item

class HumanSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "human"
    start_urls = [
        "url1",
        "url2",
     ]

    def parse(self, response):
         item = HumanItem()
         item['sex'] = response.xpath('path').extract()
         item['age'] = response.xpath('path')[1].extract()
         item['physical'] = PhysicalSpider(???)
         yield item
```

Comment: Is Spider-Man a HumanSpider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Human(scrapy.Item):
    sex = scrapy.Field()
    physical = scrapy.Field()
    full_name = scrapy.Field()

class Physical(scrapy.Item):
    height = scrapy.Field() 

p = Physical()
p['height'] = 180
h = Human()
h['physical'] = p
h['sex'] = 'yes'
return h
```

Result:

```
{'physical': {'height': 180}, 'sex': 'yes'}
```

According to your spider example:

```
class HumanSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "human"
    start_urls = [
        "url1",
     ]

    def parse(self, response):
         item = HumanItem()
         item['sex'] = response.xpath('path').extract()
         item['age'] = response.xpath('path')[1].extract()
         physical_item = Physicalitem()
         physical_item['height'] = response.xpath('path').extract()
         item['physical'] = physical_item
         yield item
```

Comment: Nice! but what will be the structure for spider? Updated question

Comment: @while1pass Why do you have two spiders? Is physical data stored on some other website or something? Could you clarify your logic with a real example, because this is just confusing.

Comment: it's only my opinion with 2 spiders. In question i have real data (a little easier than real). you answered me about Item's structure, but   what is the structure of a spider I should create for this?

Comment: What spider structure? is Human data and physical data on the same page? Check my edit, otherwise you really need to provide real world example because you're not raising any problem here to solve.

Comment: Yeeeees! It's that i need! Thank you!